# Try to init a Repo using the G cloud, for an existing project

Tags: git, command-line, gcloud, google-cloud-python, gcloud-python

There is an existing project I am a developer on with ID: placingliterature

I am attempting to run the command gcloud init placingliterature

I ran g auth and logged in properly.

I tried with or without the gitRepo already existing

I get this error:

C:\Program Files\Google\Cloud SDK>gcloud init placingliterature
Initialized gcloud directory in [C:\Program Files\Google\Cloud SDK\placingliterature.gcloud].
Cloning [https://source.developers.google.com/p/placingliterature/r/default] into [default].
Cloning into 'C:\Program Files\Google\Cloud SDK\placingliterature\default'...
Failed to erase credential: Element not found
fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://source.developers.google.com/p/placingliterature/r/default/'
ERROR: Command '['git', 'clone', 'https://source.developers.google.com/p/placingliterature/r/default', 'C:\Program File
s\Google\Cloud SDK\placingliterature\default', '--config', 'credential.helper=gcloud.cmd']' returned non-zero exit s
tatus 128
ERROR: Unable to initialize project [placingliterature], cleaning up [C:\Program Files\Google\Cloud SDK\placingliteratur
e].
ERROR: (gcloud.init) Unable to initialize project [placingliterature].

Anyone know why this is happening?

Answer (score 0):

You said that you are the developer for that project. Are you sure that you are using the same email address during gcloud auth login on which you got the permission to access that project. Secondly also check that you still have the permission or not.